# How to adjust Screen Resolution?

Tags: android

> In android there are many different types of screen Resolutions available. How to adjust the screen resolutions using java code?

Comment: +1 In our computer monitor we can do. But why cant in our mobile?

Comment: what? is it not possible? then how to manage for different screen size?

Comment: you want to design for diff resolution or change resolution like desktop ?

Comment: screen resolution is hardware defined. For best quality and performance device is "fixed" to that resolution. Maybe you should provide mutiple resorces for each resolution: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
public int AR(int input)
{       
    final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;        
    return (int) (input * scale + 0.5f);
}
```

> where, input is the value you want to use. 
>      Example:

```
ImageView TitleImage = new ImageView(this);
TitleImage.setPadding(AR(10), AR(5), AR(2), AR(3));
```

> NOW THE IMAGE PADDING SUITS ALL KINDS OF RESOLUTIONS.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to alter the screen resolution programmatically. AFAIK, you'd need to do a hardware level modification to change it.

Instead, you must write your app in a manner that it scales well across displays. Use multiple images for different sizes and densities, use dp units instead of px units. Make layouts for different screen sizes. All of this and more is explained in the online documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about how to make your App adjust to the device resolution, you should read the screen resolution using code below and make your app fill the space as your wish.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

As there are 1000s of different Android devices, you just can't have a single line of code to do it automatically for you.

If you are speaking about changing the screen resolution like in PCs. LCD screens have native resolutions which cannot be altered. However, in PCs, the driver or the hardware behind the monitor change the resolution by considering consecutive pixels as single pixel. This option is added in high resolution monitors just to keep the compatibility with old video cards. In mobile phones, we do not have a need for doing this, so there is no such options. When LCD monitors replaced CRT, they had a need to work in different resolutions like CRT which can work on more than one native resolutions.